# React Ref not getting text input field data in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using react Ref in custom input field but it is not getting input content.

I am creating some ref in React class component and using them in form custom input field refs. then i have a button in the form which has "onClick" event  to get that data. I am always getting undefined in console when i am getting "ref.current.value"

```
class LandingAfterSignIn extends React.Component {

    titleTextFieldRef = React.createRef();
    shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef = React.createRef();
    longDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef = React.createRef();
    imageFieldRef = React.

createRef();
    webFieldRef = React.createRef();
    contactTextFieldRef = React.createRef();

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // we use this to make the card to appear after the page has been rendered
    this.state = {
        cardAnimaton: "cardHidden",
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
    };

   // super(props);




    this.state = {
        errors: []
    };

}



render() {
    let image= require("assets/img/landing-bg.jpg") ;
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;

    //let titleTextFieldRef= this.titleTextFieldRef  ;
    //let  shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef  = this.shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef ;

    return (
        <div
            className={classes.pageHeader}
            style={{
                backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")",
                backgroundSize: "cover",
                backgroundPosition: "top center",
                width: "100%"
            }}
        >
            <Header
                color="transparent"
                routes={dashboardRoutes}
                brand="StockNap"
                rightLinks={<HeaderLinks />}
                fixed
                changeColorOnScroll={{
                    height: 400,
                    color: "white"
                }}
                {...rest}
            />
            <div>
                <div className={classes.container}>

                    <div className={classes.container}>
                        <GridContainer>
                            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>

                                <h1 className={classes.title}>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName} </h1>
                                <FirebaseDatabaseMutation type="push" path="user_bookmarks">
                                    {({ runMutation }) => (
                                        <form>


                                            <GridContainer>
                                                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                                        <CustomInput
                                                            labelText="Company Name/Title"
                                                            id="titleTextField"
                                                            formControlProps={{
                                                                fullWidth: true
                                                            }}
                                                            inputRef={this.titleTextFieldRef}
                                                            >
                                                        </CustomInput>
                                                    </GridItem>
                                                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                                        <CustomInput
                                                            labelText="short Description"
                                                            id="shortDescription"
                                                            formControlProps={{
                                                                fullWidth: true,
                                                                className: classes.textArea
                                                            }}
                                                            inputRef={this.shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef}
                                                        />
                                                    </GridItem>
                                                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                                        <CustomInput
                                                            labelText="long Description"
                                                            id="longDescription"
                                                            formControlProps={{
                                                                fullWidth: true,
                                                                className: classes.textArea
                                                            }}
                                                            inputProps={{
                                                                multiline: true,
                                                                rows: 2
                                                            }}
                                                            inputRef={this.longDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef}
                                                        />
                                                    </GridItem>
                                                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                                    <CustomInput
                                                        labelText="contact"
                                                        id="contactTextField"
                                                        formControlProps={{
                                                            fullWidth: true,

                                                        }}

                                                        inputRef={this.contactTextFieldRef}
                                                    />
                                                </GridItem>

                                                    <Button
                                                        style={{
                                                            width: 50,
                                                            height: 50,
                                                            alignSelf: "center",
                                                            background: "#039BE5",
                                                            color: "white"
                                                        }}
                                                        variant="fab"
                                                        type="submit"
                                                        onClick={async ev => {
                                                            console.log("submit") ;
                                                            ev.preventDefault();
                                                            ev.stopPropagation();
                                                            ev.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();


                                                            const titleTextField = get(
                                                                this.titleTextFieldRef,
                                                                "current.value",
                                                                ""
                                                            );
                                                            const shortDescriptionMetaTextField = get(
                                                                this.shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef,
                                                                "current.value",
                                                                ""
                                                            );
                                                            const longDescriptionkMetaTextField = get(
                                                                this.longDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef,
                                                                "current.value",
                                                                ""
                                                            );
                                                            const contactTextField = get(
                                                                this.contactTextFieldRef,
                                                                "current.value",
                                                                ""
                                                            );

                                                            console.log(this.titleTextFieldRef);
                                                            console.log(this.shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef);

                                                            await runMutation({
                                                                titleTextField: titleTextField,
                                                                shortDescriptionMetaTextField: shortDescriptionMetaTextField,
                                                                created_at: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                                                                updated_at: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                                                            });


                                                            set(this.titleTextFieldRef, "current.value", "");
                                                           set(this.shortDescriptionMetaTextFieldRef, "current.value", "");
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        +
                                                    </Button>

                                                </GridContainer>

                                        </form>
                                    )}
                                </FirebaseDatabaseMutation>

                            </GridItem>
                        </GridContainer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classNames(classes.main, classes.mainRaised)}>
                <div className={classes.container}>

                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I want to add one more information , customInput are functional components
i want reference from parents to go into that

```
function CustomInput({ ...props }) {
  const {
    classes,
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    white,
    inputRootCustomClasses,
    success
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true,
    [classes.whiteUnderline]: white
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [inputRootCustomClasses]: inputRootCustomClasses !== undefined
  });
  const inputClasses = classNames({
    [classes.input]: true,
    [classes.whiteInput]: white
  });
  var formControlClasses;
  if (formControlProps !== undefined) {
    formControlClasses = classNames(
      formControlProps.className,
      classes.formControl
    );
  } else {
    formControlClasses = classes.formControl;
  }
  return (
    <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlClasses}>
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + " " + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          input: inputClasses,
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses
        }}
        id={id}
        {...inputProps}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't use refs to access other components, it is a very bad practice. Use state and props to pass values between components.

Comment: lot of blogs saying , using stats based approach is generating lot of boiler plate code. ref are easy to do redundant work. Does current issue due to stateless custom functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> In the typical React dataflow, props are the only way that parent components interact with their children. To modify a child, you re-render it with new props.
>
> Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to “own” that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. See the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) guide for examples of this.

Currently, you're exactly doing what you should not be doing: using refs to access component methods. That is **anti-pattern** and make your code **suceptible to bugs** like you're experiencing right now. You should either:

- Lift the state up if you need to pass data from one component to another
- Use state container libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) if you need to trigger actions

In either way I strongly advise you to refactor your code in either direction.

Comment: thanks! work around using stats and passing callback is what in initial reactjs learning steps but why  refs to functional component is not useful ?

Comment: @donald they are *useful* but only for managing focus and interact with non-react pieces of the code base. You should not overuse them because they break the React flow. In the case of a React-only app, you should therefore not use them :)